# How can I return a promise from the server in sveltekit?

Tags: javascript, async-await, svelte, sveltekit

What's to preferred way to asynchronously return a promise from the server that I can then await in my .svelte page?

Use case: I would like to call an external api from a function in /lib/server/utils.js but do not want to wait for the response before rendering the page.

This an example of the functionality I want to achieve, simulating a 3 second delay, and it works as I'd expect: svelte renders the page with loading text until the promise is resolved then renders the results of the function call.

```
//in +page.svelte
<script>
    async function getActivities() {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(resolve, 3000, [
                {
                    name: 'activity name',
                    sport_type: 'sport',
                    map: {
                        summary_polyline: 'polyline',
                    }
                },
            ]);
        });
    }
</script>

<h1>Activities</h1>
{#await getActivities()}
    Loading activities...
{:then activities}
    {#each activities as activity}
        <h3>{activity.name} {activity.sport_type}</h3>
        <p>Details: {activity.map.summary_polyline}</p>
    {/each}
{/await}
```

What I would like to do while keeping the same functionality of displaying a loading message until the data is returned. But doesn't work because load() is called and resolved before the page is rendered.

```
//in lib/server.utils.js
export async function getActivities() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, 3000, [
            {
                name: 'activity name',
                sport_type: 'sport',
                map: {
                    summary_polyline: 'polyline',
                }
            },
        ]);
    });
}

//in +page.server.js
import { getActivities } from '$lib/server/utils.js';

export async function load() {
    return {
        activityPromise: getActivities(),
    };
}

//in +page.svelte
<script>
    export let data;
    $: activityPromise = data.activityPromise;
</script>

<h1>Activities</h1>
{#await activityPromise}
    Loading activities...
{:then activities}
    {#each activities as activity}
        <h3>{activity.name} {activity.sport_type}</h3>
        <p>Details: {activity.map.summary_polyline}</p>
    {/each}
{/await}
```

Comment: Starting in SvelteKit 2, top-level promises returned from a `load` function are no longer automatically awaited by the framework. So the code you wrote in the 2nd part of your question will work as you desired. (I tested it.) https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/migrating-to-sveltekit-2#top-level-promises-are-no-longer-awaited

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

1. Expose `getActivities()` as a [regular API endpoint](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#server) (vs. [page endpoint](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#page-page-js)). This allows you to get the JSON payload by fetching an internal API URL like `/api/get-activities`.
2. `fetch()` this new internal API endpoint from +page.svelte. Of course, `fetch()` returns a promise that can be `#await`ed. You may have to guard this `fetch()` with [`onMount`](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/onmount) or [`browser`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-environment-browser) so SvelteKit does not try to "prefetch" from the server.